# How do I create dynamic list using WhatsApp API?

Tags: node.js, arrays, json, chatbot, whatsapp

I'm writing a program in Node.js to create a WhatsApp chatbot that sends a List messages based on the different information to users.
This is the desired Output:

I'm trying to find a way where I don't need to hard code the row titles for different list messages every time and the method should automatically generate this part

```
{"title":"row 1 title"}, {"title":"row 2 title"} .... {"title":"row n title"}
```

I wrote a method that takes an array of title values as an argument and generates a list based on that. But the message is not sent and I don't see any errors. I'm using WATI API as my whatsapp provider.

1. https://docs.wati.io/reference/post_api-v1-sendinteractivelistmessage
2. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/guides/interactive-messages/

**server.js**

```
// packages
const express = require('express');
require('dotenv').config("./env");
const WA = require('./whatsapp.js');
const cors = require('cors');

const webApp = express();

webApp.use(express.json());
webApp.use(cors());



// Route for WhatsApp
webApp.post('/whatsapp', async (req, res) => {

   
        var data = ['row 1', 'row 2']
        WA.sendListInteractive(data, whatsapp_number)
  
    res.end();
}
);

webApp.listen(process.env.PORT, () => {

    console.log(`Server is up and running at ${process.env.PORT}`);
});
```

**whatsapp.js**

```
    const sendListInteractive = async (data, senderID) => {
        data = []
        var options = {
            'method': 'POST',
            'url': 'https://' + process.env.URL + '/api/v1/sendInteractiveListMessage?whatsappNumber=' + senderID,
            'headers': {
                'Authorization': process.env.API,
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                "header": "", //optional
                "body": "Body",
                "footer": "", //optional
                "buttonText": "Button Text",
                "sections": [
                    {
                        "title": "string",
                        "rows": [
                            data.forEach(
                                e => {
                                    {
                                        "title :" + e
                                    }
                                }
                            )
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            })
    
        };
        request(options, function (error, response) {
            if (error) console.log(error);
            console.log(response.body);
        });
    }
```

Output:
[image: Output when the program is executed]

Any help or advice is appreciated!.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to this answer [How do I create dynamic list using WhatsApp API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72684520/how-do-i-create-dynamic-list-using-whatsapp-api)
Create the genJSON() function as suggested.

This is just an example, you can invoke the function as per your requirement

**method.js**

```
const WA = require("./whatsapp")

function genJSON() {
  var arr = ['row 1', 'row 2', 'row3']
  try {
    let d = []
    for (const row of arr) {
      d.push({
        title: row
      })
    }
    console.log(d)
WA.sendListInteractive (d, whatsapp_number)

  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e)
  }
}
genJSON()
```

**modified whatsapp.js**

```
const sendListInteractive = async (jsonData, senderID) => {
        data = []
        var options = {
            'method': 'POST',
            'url': 'https://' + process.env.URL + '/api/v1/sendInteractiveListMessage?whatsappNumber=' + senderID,
            'headers': {
                'Authorization': process.env.API,
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                "header": "", //optional
                "body": "Body",
                "footer": "", //optional
                "buttonText": "Button Text",
                "sections": [
                    {
                        "title": "string",
                        "rows": jsonData //changes
                    }
                ]
            })
    
        };
        request(options, function (error, response) {
            if (error) console.log(error);
            console.log(response.body);
        });
    }
```